# Directory permission showing d?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, terminal, filesystems, directory

I downloaded some files and saved them in a folder on an external hard drive. Later when I am trying to search for the folder I couldn't find it. So I try searching using the terminal. I listed all the files in the location where I had saved that folder previously and noticed the folder was present there but it showed `d?????????` permission. What does it mean and how can I get my files back.

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 chetan chetan      4096 Jun 12 21:55 'Money Heist'
d????????? ? ?      ?              ?            ?  Naruto_Shippuden
drwxrwxrwx 1 chetan chetan      4096 Jul 20 23:51  Parasyte
```

Comment: What filesystem is on this external drive? What does `file Naruto_Shippuden` output? Please  [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/667034/edit) your question to include this information

Comment: here, I would think that may suggest a broken filesystem. (It could happen normally if you only have read permission (and not access permission) to the directory, but then you wouldn't see the same information about the other files either.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably an issue with either the file system of the external drive and/or the permissions set.
You can try to list the files as `root` by changing to the `root` user via `sudo -i`, `root` can read everything, therefore this will temporarily solve all the permission issues.

To make the files usable as your normal logged in user you can change the permissions.
Set the permissions to something normal by.

```
sudo chmod -R 660 Naruto_Shippuden
```

This will set the files read and writable.

Display your login name via `whoami`.
And then change the owner of `Naruto_Shippuden` to you.

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<user> Naruto_Shippuden
```

Where `<user>` is whatever `whoami` displayed. (not root!!)

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same issue.  ubuntu 20.04 and RHEL8 mounting from Windows server.  nfs3 works fine  NFS4 has the issue.  What we have noticed is if the Windows directory has more than 26 different ntfs permissions (ACLs) we are Ok.  the mount is fine and I can access the directory from the windows share.  once we go over 26 ACLs it gives us the all ?marks.  I remove and try 26 or less and it mounts fine and I can access the directory that had the problem.  We are not using kerbose

Comment: This is interesting information, but the question here involves an external drive, not NFS. As such, this doesn’t answer the question. You may want to write this up as a self-answered Q&A.